# Actually i am trying to add banner like this it is showing slider banner but slider scrolling is working?

Tags: magento2

```
<div class="container">
<h4>Shop &gt; Homeware</h4>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"><!-- Indicators --><ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li class="active" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol><!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active"><img style="width: 100%;" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/slider/bizkick-home-banner-2.png"}}" alt="Los Angeles" /></div>
<div class="item"><img style="width: 100%;" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/slider/bizkick-home-banner-1.png"}}" alt="Chicago" /></div>
<div class="item"><img style="width: 100%;" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/slider/bizkick-home-banner-2.png"}}" alt="New york" /></div>
</div>
<!-- Left and right controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a></div>
<div class="row text-center">
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="button cat_range"><button class="btn btn-danger">SHOP ALL HOMEWARES</button></div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Featured section --></div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init" xml="space">// <![CDATA[
    requirejs(['jquery', 'jquery.bootstrap'], function (jQuery, jQueryBootstrap) {
        jQuery('.carousel').carousel();
    });
// ]]></script>
```

> E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layoutdefault.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <referenceBlock name="head">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Head\Script" name="requirejs" before="-">
            <arguments>

                <argument name="file" xsi:type="string">requirejs/require.js</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

        <block class="Magento\RequireJs\Block\Html\Head\Config" name="requirejs-config" after="requirejs"/>
    </referenceBlock> 
</page>
```

> E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\js\requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        "jquery.bootstrap": "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min"
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery.bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

> It is showing error like this in console log-

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
require.js:1895 Active resource loading counts reached to a per-frame limit while the tab is in background. Network requests will be delayed until a previous loading finishes, or the tab is foregrounded. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5527160148197376 for more details
/mage/pub/static/version1538397459/frontend/Hiddentechies/bizkick/en_US/jquery/jquery-storageapi.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1/mage/pub/static/version1538397459/frontend/Hiddentechies/bizkick/en_US/jquery/jquery-storageapi.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
require.js:141 Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery/jquery-storageapi
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
/mage/pub/static/version1538397459/frontend/Hiddentechies/bizkick/en_US/bizkickowlcarousel.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1/mage/pub/static/version1538397459/frontend/Hiddentechies/bizkick/en_US/bizkickowlcarousel.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
require.js:141 Uncaught Error: Script error for: bizkickowlcarousel
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
/mage/pub/static/version1538397459/frontend/Hiddentechies/bizkick/en_US/jquery.bootstrap.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1/mage/pub/static/version1538397459/frontend/Hiddentechies/bizkick/en_US/jquery.bootstrap.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
require.js:141 Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery.bootstrap
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
/mage/pub/static/version1538397459/frontend/Hiddentechies/bizkick/en_US/validation.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1/mage/pub/static/version1538397459/frontend/Hiddentechies/bizkick/en_US/validation.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
main.js:37 Error: Script error for: validation
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
(anonymous) @ main.js:37
```

[image]